# Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I need to find the Fourier Transform of

$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$

Where the Fourier Tranform is of $f$ is denoted as $\hat{f}$, where $\hat{f}$ is defined as $$\hat{f}(y)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)e^{-ixy}dx$$

I think I need to use the Fourier Inversion Theorem. From this theorem, I think we know that $\widehat{\widehat{\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}}} = (2\pi)\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$

Then from the Fourier Inversion Theorem, I got that $\widehat{\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}} = \int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}e^{ixy}dx = \int_\mathbb{R}\frac{cos(xy)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$

From here, I am unsure about how to calculate the integral, assuming I did everything right so far. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The Maple command $$with(inttrans):
fourier(1/(x^2+1)^2, x, s);
 $$ produces $$1/2\,\pi \, \left( 1+s \right) {\it Heaviside} \left( s \right) {
{\rm e}^{-s}}+1/2\,{{\rm e}^{s}}\pi \,{\it Heaviside} \left( -s
 \right)  \left( -s+1 \right)
  .$$

Comment: The inversion theorem is a red herring. The integral you found can be obtained by just plugging in directly into the definition of the Fourier transform!

Comment: The question comes directly from a section of Frank Jones' "Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Spaces" that emphasizes the inversion formula.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Method 1: Residues**

Consider the contour integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{i k z}}{(1+z^2)^2}$$

where $C$ is a semicircle in the upper half plane; here, $k>0$.  Then by the residue theorem and Jordan's lemma:

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx  \frac{e^{i k x}}{(1+x^2)^2} &= i 2 \pi \operatorname*{Res}_{z=i} \frac{e^{i k z}}{(1+z^2)^2}\\ &= i 2 \pi \left [\frac{d}{dz} \frac{e^{i k z}}{(z+i)^2} \right ]_{z=i}\\ &= i 2 \pi \left [\frac{i k\, e^{i k z}}{(z+i)^2} - \frac{2 e^{i k z}}{(z+i)^3} \right ]_{z=i}\\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} (k+1) e^{-k}\end{align}$$

For $k \lt 0$, $C$ is a semicircle in the lower half plane; for the same reasons as above, we have:

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx  \frac{e^{i k x}}{(1+x^2)^2} &= -i 2 \pi \operatorname*{Res}_{z=-i} \frac{e^{i k z}}{(1+z^2)^2}\\ &= -i 2 \pi \left [\frac{d}{dz} \frac{e^{i k z}}{(z-i)^2} \right ]_{z=-i}\\ &= -i 2 \pi \left [\frac{i k\, e^{i k z}}{(z-i)^2} - \frac{2 e^{i k z}}{(z-i)^3} \right ]_{z=-i}\\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} (-k+1) e^{k}\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx  \frac{e^{i k x}}{(1+x^2)^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} (1+|k|) e^{-|k|}$$

**Method 2: Convolution**

Knowing that the FT of $1/(1+x^2)$ is $\pi \, e^{-|k|}$, we may use the convolution theorem to deduce that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx  \frac{e^{i k x}}{(1+x^2)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk' e^{-|k'|} \, e^{-|k-k'|}$$

Again, the way we evaluate the integral on the RHS depends on the sign of $k$.  For $k \gt 0$, this integral is

$$\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-\infty}^0 dk' \, e^{k'} \, e^{-(k-k')} + \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^k dk' \, e^{-k'} \, e^{-(k-k')}+ \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{k}^{\infty} dk' \, e^{-k'} \, e^{k-k'}$$

For $k \lt 0$, on the other hand, the integral is

$$\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-\infty}^k dk' \, e^{k'} \, e^{-(k-k')} + \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{k}^0 dk' \, e^{k'} \, e^{k-k'}+ \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} dk' \, e^{-k'} \, e^{k-k'}$$

Evaluation of the above integrals reproduces the result derived above.

Comment: Nice answer. Though I somewhat doubt the OP knows the Fourier Transform of $(1+x^2)^{-1}$. I certainly don't "know it" myself if you just asked me in the hallway.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thank you.  Maybe - nothing in the OP's question provides evidence one way or another.  If asked, I will provide a link; that FT is one of the first ones learned when studying FTs.

Comment: Knowing the answer verifying it is easy. But for the forward direction, I suppose the proof is also via residues? Or is there a more clever way?

Comment: @WillieWong: The proof I know is via residues - you can see how it will go by following the proof above.  (It is very easy compared with the current problem.)  Of course there is a different way...what it is, though, I am not clever enough to divine.

Comment: Thank you, this was incredibly helpful. I did know the FT of $(1+x^2)^{-1}$, so the second way is my favorite.

Comment: What about the FT of $(1+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$? How to show it by convolution theorem?

Comment: Once a contour in the upper half-plane obtains the $k>0$ case, you can get the $k<0$ case without another contour integration by noting $k\mapsto-k$ conjugates the integral (in this case, that does nothing), often a useful trick in taking the FT of a function that's real-valued on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Hello Ron. I have a basic question. Why are you not considering $k=0$ in say, doing the convolution?

Comment: @psie: Take ">" to be "$\ge$".

Answer (score 2):

**Tools:**
$$\mathcal F[f]=\hat f (\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-i\xi x} \mathrm dx $$
$$D \hat f=-i\widehat{xf} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$ \widehat{Df}=i\xi \hat f \tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$g(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}\quad\quad \hat g(\xi)=\pi e^{-|\xi|} \tag{3}\label{3}$$

---

We want to compute the Fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$.
We begin with $g(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$, noting that:
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac1{1+x^2}=-\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2} $$
namely $g'(x)=-2xf(x)$.
By $\eqref{2}$, $\mathcal F[-2xf]=\mathcal F[g']=i\xi\hat g\stackrel{\eqref{3}}=i\xi\pi e^{-|\xi|}$. Hence:
$$-2 \mathcal F[xf]=i\xi\pi e^{-|\xi|} $$
By $\eqref1$, $\mathcal F[xf]=i D \hat f$, so at the end we get:
$$-2i D \hat f= i\xi\pi e^{-|\xi|}$$
Now we consider two different cases $\xi \ge 0$ and $\xi <0$ and we integrate:
$$\hat f(\xi)=\frac{\pi}2(1+|\xi|)e^{-|\xi|}+c $$
Since $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$, by the [Riemann–Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) $\hat f(\xi)\to 0$ as $|\xi|\to \infty$, so we conclude that $c=0$.
Finally:
$$\hat f(\xi)=\frac{\pi}2(1+|\xi|)e^{-|\xi|}$$