# Gaussian convolution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, gaussian

$X$ and $Y$ are standard normal independent random variables, let $Z=XY$. Is the distribution of $Z$ equal to $N(0,\frac{1}{2})$?

I tried using convolution to get the distribution of $Z$. Is it correct?

Comment: You should add your attempts to your question.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Just a thing: please use MathJax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it's as easy as including your math between dollar symbols. Enjoy your stay and good luck!

Comment: Sorry, no. Convolution  is for the sum of variables.

Comment: we multiply the pdf''s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar formula for the distribution of the product $Z=XY$ of two nicely behaved random variables: $$ f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(t)f_Y(z/t)\frac{1}{|t|}dt.$$ So in this case with two standard normals, that's $$ f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t^2+\frac{z^2}{t^2})}\frac{dt}{|t|}.$$ There's no way to integrate this in terms of elementary functions, but we can get it into a well-known integral representation of a well-known special function:

If we let $u= t/\sqrt{|z|},$ this gives $$ f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|z|\frac{1}{2}(u^2+1/u^2)}\frac{du}{|u|}$$ and letting $w=2\ln(u)$ gives $$ f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-|z|\cosh(w)}dw = \frac{1}{\pi}K_0(|z|)$$ where $K_0$ is the [modified Bessel function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) (The relevant integral formula is both on the wikipedia page and [here.](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32))

---

You mentioned in the comments going the route of characteristic equations, and that works too. We have $$ \phi_Z(t)=E(e^{itZ}) = E(e^{itXY}) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itxy-x^2/2-y^2/2}dxdy.$$ You can complete the square to $$ \phi_Z(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy e^{-y^2(1+t^2)/2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-ity)^2}dx.$$ The $x$ integral is just a shifted standard Gaussian (shifted in an imaginary direction, but that doesn't wind up mattering), so is just $\sqrt{2\pi},$ so we get $$ \phi_Z(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(1+t^2) dy} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2} \frac{du}{\sqrt{2\pi}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}.$$

But then, if you want the PDF, there's the work of doing the inverse Fourier transform to compute it from the characteristic function. Using [this answer,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541222/compute-integral-int-infty-infty-frace-ixt-sqrt1x2-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1) we obtain $$ F_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-izt}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} 2K_0(|z|) = \frac{1}{\pi}K_0(|z|),$$ exactly as above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Figured where I missed it

Answer (score 0):

The sum Z=X+Y is Gaussian distributed, with the variance being the sum of variances of X and Y.
It can "easily" be shown using the characteristic function (Fourier of the probability density function).

I don't think the product is Gaussian.

Comment: Yes, just figured it's not gaussian. Characteristic equation is the best way to go. The characteristic eqn of summed iid RV is the product of their individual characteristic equation. Do you know the characteristic equation when the two RV are multiplied. Given we have the  characteristic equation of each RV